# Fix Issue with React Material-table to Display Remote Data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, es6-promise, material-table

I have a remote data which is sent as array object. I convert this to JSON array in order to show this data in Material data table. I am able to call the API and when I log the response I can see the converted JSON as the data below:

```
[{"xxxx":"xxxx","yyyy":5,"zzzz":3,"tttt":1,"qqqqq":"some-data"}]
```

Unfortunately I am unable to show this data in the table while also implementing paging as well. Please find my codes below and assist me to fix this issue:

```
data={query =>
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let formData = new FormData();
            const userid = 'someID'

            formData.append('userid', userid);
            const config = {
              headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
            };

            let url = 'http://urlendpoint?'
            url += 'per_page=' + query.pageSize
            url += '&page=' + (query.page + 1)
            fetch(url, {
              method: 'POST',
              body: formData,
              config
            })
              .then(response => response.json())
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.response);
              })
              .then(result => {
                let resultData = JSON.stringify(result);
                console.log('result: ' + resultData);
                resolve({
                  data: resultData,
                  page: resultData.page - 1,
                  totalCount: resultData.total,
                })
              })
          })
        }
```

Also, I am following this link to implement the material table: https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/remote-data

Comment: Which component do you use for material-table. If possible please add a link for it

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri This is the link I am following https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/remote-data

Comment: I think instead of using `resultData.data`, you are actually passing `resultData` to the table which is a problem. Changing to `resolve({
                  data: resultData.data,
                  page: resultData.page - 1,
                  totalCount: resultData.total,
                })` will work, assuming you output provides data as a key

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri this the data that I receive as an array object [{"xxxx":"xxxx","yyyy":5,"zzzz":3,"tttt":1,"qqqqq":"some-data"}] and I convert it to JSON. so my JSON does not provide data as a key.

Comment: ok but then you try to use resultData.total and resultData.page which I assume won't be present too. Also you stringify your resultData which is what the table won't want

Comment: In that case how do I convert the array object I receive to a JSON array for the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually removed the conversion to JSON string and everything works fine. See my updated codes below:

```
data={query =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    const userid = 'someID'

    formData.append('userid', userid);
    const config = {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    };

    let url = 'http://urlendpoint?'
    url += 'per_page=' + query.pageSize
    url += '&page=' + (query.page + 1)
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      config
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      })
      .then(result => {
            resolve({
              data: result,
              page: result.page - 1,
              totalCount: result.total,
            })
          })
  })
}
```